# ORACLE APEX-LOWCODE:HTTP Failure-"An error occurred during URL invocation. ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure

Tags: oracle-apex, http-error, lowcode

[image: ERROR]

I am using REST DATA SOURCE in apex low code.
When I call an API. I am getting this error:

> "An error occurred during URL invocation.
>
> ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure".

This API is working in Postman.

Why has this error occurred? How to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It works in Postman" is comparing apples to pears in a way. Postman connects your client to the API endpoint. In oracle APEX the connection is initiated *from within the database*. There are 2 things that needs to be setup for this. First, an ACL is needed. This will allow any processes in the database to connect to the remote host. This looks fine in your setup since you get an error that indicates you already reached the host. Second, the SSL certificate needs to be added to the Oracle wallet. There are many blogs on how to do this, [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl) is one example

Comment: it is likely that Oracle APEX REST Data Source API requires an SSL certificate to establish a secure connection to the remote host .Am I correct?

Comment: It's not "likely", it is "certain". ORDS uses the wallet configuration in the underlying database.